# Flutter - AnimatedSwitcher isn't smooth

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've implemented an animation of images, what I wanted to do was create a custom circular spinner with images that switch to give this effect, the problem is that with AnimatedSwitcher for a little fraction of time there's a black space between one image and another.

Here's the code of the animation:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    child: Image.asset(
        values[_index % values.length],
        key: UniqueKey(),
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
    ),
)
```

Is there a way to solve this issue or an alternative to AnimatedSwitcher?

Comment: Did you try this when building app with `--release` flag? Or you just try in emulator?

Comment: I tried it on a real device and it does the same

Comment: Doesnt really matter if real device or not, did you build using `--release` tag?

Comment: Thank you, now I tried but unfortunately I have the same result

Answer (score 0):

The second image might need some time to be loaded into memory. I had the similar issue before but solved it with a workaround. I used a `FadeInImage` with a transparent placeholder on top of the previous image:

```dart
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

Stack(
  children: [
    Image(
      image: previousImage,
    ),
    FadeInImage(
      fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
      image: currentImage,
    )
  ],
),
```

`transparent_image` was a dependency I added in pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple images with this method? because I have a sequence of 9 images

Comment: I would think through a state update of previousImage and currentImage. You'll need to manage that yourself, though

Comment: I will try that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think precacheImage would be help you. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html

I write a same function like you, but I have not get a black space between image. But if I do not set the Key of Image, then I would got a black space.